# Does exist other techniques for finding PDF/CDF from relation between random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

I know two techniques of finding CDF/PDF from relation between random variables. By relation I mean that one rv is represented by other, examples $ Y = X^2 $ or $ Z = \frac {U} {1-U} $.
Summarizing, to find PDF/CDF in general cases with proper assumption for each method I can use Change-of-Variable Technique ($ f_Y = f_X |\frac {dx} {dy}| $) or Distribution Function Technique ($ P(Y \leq g(X)) $).
Can you help me to find some other techniques? Can you give me some keywords, articles which should I search? Or maybe can you just describe the other techniques here?
Sorry if it is not well formalized, I am not an mathematician, I have tried what I can. I hope it is understandable.

Comment: supposing you know the moment generating function of a random variable $X$, $M_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{tX}]$, then you can often deduce which distribution $X$ is based on this.

For example, supposing we have $n$ iid Exp($\lambda$) random variables $X_1,..., X_n$. You can find the MGF of $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and this will be the same as the MGF of the Gamma distribution. Hence you can deduce that $S_n$ must in fact be gamma. Then you know what the PDF/CDF are based on knowing the distribution type.

Comment: Yes I know this technique, but it is more guessing that deriving. What I am searching could be some technique going through or using MGF or CH or kumulants or any other in the middle and finishing with PDF, CDF.